# nginx ssi on через rewrite

Tags: nginx, ssi

Мне нужно, что бы SSI в Nginx был включен не на всех страницах, а только в определенном location
Вот (упрощенный) пример конфига, который у меня работает:

```
location = /main.php {
    ssi on;
    include  php5_provider;
}
```

так ssi включается, а мне нужно, что бы он включался в следующем виде:

```
location ~* ^/[-\w]+\.htm$ {
    ssi_types *;
    ssi on;
    rewrite ^  /main.php?$uri last;
}

location = /main.php {
    include  php5_provider;
}
```

Вот так SSI у меня не работает.

```
$nginx -t
```

проходит нормально, но следующий ssi блок никак не обрабатывается:

```
<!--#include file="ssi.htm"-->
```

Как это можно исправить?

UPDATE:
Временно изобрел такой костыль:

```
location ~* ^/[-\w]+\.htm$ {
  ssi on;
  include  php5_provider;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /main.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/main.php;
  fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $uri&$query_string;
  break;
}
```

Уверен, существует более элегантное и гибкое решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто инструкция "`rewrite ^  /main.php?$uri last;`" забирает все запросы на себя (в скрипт `main.php`) и дело до `SSI` не доходит.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется что дело скорее всего в rewrite (я даже отразил это в заголовке вопроса).
Вопрос в том, как в подобной конфигурации не включать SSI для всех страниц, а ограничить определенным location'ом.